# Best way to check 2d matrix in python

Tags: python, exception, indexing

I Java, to check a grid and it's neighbors, we could always write things like
`matrix[row - 1][col], matrix[row][col - 1], 
 matrix[row + 1][col], matrix[row][col + 1]`

And try to handle exception in catch, if it's out of boundary.
However, python allows negative indexing,which will not cause exceptions.
 Is there any elegant way to do similar things like it in Java?

Comment: start from zero and overflow to the right instead of to the left, you'll get the equivalent to Java's `indexOutOfBounds`

Comment: Even in Java, this wouldn't have been a good way to do it. Python is fairly unique in that its culture encourages using exceptions for ordinary control flow. Deliberately triggering an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is a very strange thing to do in Java.

Comment: You will get an exception depending on what the negative index is.

Comment: You could define your own `Matrix` class that over-loaded indexing to do the range checking you want. If row index was in-bounds, it would return a `Row` class instance would have done something similar (over-load indexing).